# Writing read/write AD Records via a web service

Tags: active-directory, web-services

We are moving from Domino to hosted Exchange. We currently have 2 directories, Domino and AD. We are looking for ways to integrate the two, and some of our other systems. For example, users are created in our web-bases HR system, and some of the data will come from there.

I understand that there is such a thing as ADWS (Active Directory Web Services), but from doing some readying and researching I cannot determine if this is a *real* web service that I can use to get and put data into AD. Understand that you can use PowerShell or C#; would prefer Java.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: In regards to the coexistence you might look at something like this. Trying to do it on your own is probably a recipe for pain. - https://www.quest.com/products/coexistence-manager-for-notes/

Comment: That looks like a good product. We are also considering a product from Binary Age. I would still like to know if it is possible to use web services - we want to be able to have a single repository for our employee data.